# Apexcharts doesn't works properly when dashboard load. It appears sometimes and sometimes don't

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, apexcharts

I am facing an issue with displaying apexcharts on dashboard. I have 5 charts in dashboard and the charts behavior is pretty weird. All charts appears after reload the page 3 to 4 times or when clicked on inspect element. Otherwise shows 2 or 3 charts.How to fix this issue.

Let's have a look...
This is the Js file where Iam fetching all the data through ajax.
when I do console log I can see values in data key.

```
var revenueData = [];
var fetchEarningData = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "dashboard/earning",
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery.map(data, function (n) {
                revenueData.push(n)

            });
        },
        complete: function (data) {
        },

        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
}

var customerData = [];
var fetchCustomerData = function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "dashboard/customer",
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            customerData.push(data)
        },
        complete: function (data) {
        },

        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
var fetchMemberData = function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "dashboard/member",
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            customerData.push(data)
        },
        complete: function (data) {
        },

        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
var orderData = [];
var fetchOrderData = function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "dashboard/order",
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery.map(data, function(n) {
                orderData.push(n)

            });
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            handleRenderChart()
        },

        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
};
var stockInAmount = [];
var fetchStockInAmountData = function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "dashboard/stockIn-amount",
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            // console.log('new',data)
            // Prepare series &  xaxis category data for stacked100 region chart
            jQuery.map(data, function (n) {
                stockInAmount.push(n)

            });
        },
        complete: function (data) {

        },

        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
   }
var debitData = [];
var fetchDebitData = function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "dashboard/debit-amount",
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery.map(data, function(n) {
                debitData.push(n)
            });
        },
        complete: function (data) {
        },

        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
var creditData = [];
var fetchCreditData = function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "dashboard/credit-amount",
        type: "Get",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        data: {
        },

        success: function (data) {
            jQuery.map(data, function(n) {
                creditData.push(n)
            });
        },
        complete: function (data) {
        },

        error: function (data) {

        }
    });
}

var handleRenderChart = function() {
    // global apexchart settings
    Apex = {
        title: {
            style: {
                fontSize:  '14px',
                fontWeight:  'bold',
                fontFamily:  app.font.family,
                color:  app.color.white
            },
        },
        legend: {
            fontFamily: app.font.family,
            labels: {
                colors: '#fff'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            style: {
        fontSize: '12px',
        fontFamily: app.font.family
      }
        },
        grid: {
            borderColor: 'rgba('+ app.color.whiteRgb + ', .25)',
        },
        dataLabels: {
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontFamily: app.font.family,
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                colors: undefined
        }
        },
        xaxis: {
            axisBorder: {
                show: true,
                color: 'rgba('+ app.color.whiteRgb + ', .25)',
                height: 1,
                width: '100%',
                offsetX: 0,
                offsetY: -1
            },
            axisTicks: {
                show: true,
                borderType: 'solid',
                color: 'rgba('+ app.color.whiteRgb + ', .25)',
                height: 6,
                offsetX: 0,
                offsetY: 0
            },
      labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: '#fff',
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontFamily: app.font.family,
                    fontWeight: 400,
                    cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
                }
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
      labels: {
                style: {
                    colors: '#fff',
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontFamily: app.font.family,
                    fontWeight: 400,
                    cssClass: 'apexcharts-xaxis-label',
                }
            }
        }
    };


  // small stat chart
    var x = 0;
    var chart = [];


    var elmList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-render="apexchart"]'));
    elmList.map(function(elm) {
        var chartType = elm.getAttribute('data-type');
        var chartHeight = elm.getAttribute('data-height');
        var chartTitle = elm.getAttribute('data-title');
        var chartColors = [];
        var chartPlotOptions = {};
        var chartData = [];
        var chartStroke = {
            show: false
        };

        if (chartType === 'bar') {

            chartColors = [app.color.theme];
            chartPlotOptions = {
                bar: {
                    horizontal: false,
                    columnWidth: '65%',
                    endingShape: 'rounded'
                }
            };
            chartData = [{
                name: chartTitle,
                data:  revenueData
            }];
        } else if (chartType === 'pie') {
            chartColors = ['rgba('+ app.color.themeRgb + ', 1)', 'rgba('+ app.color.themeRgb + ', .75)', 'rgba('+ app.color.themeRgb + ', .5)'];
            chartData = customerData
        } else if (chartType === 'donut') {
            chartColors = ['rgba('+ app.color.themeRgb + ', .15)', 'rgba('+ app.color.themeRgb + ', .35)', 'rgba('+ app.color.themeRgb + ', .55)', 'rgba('+ app.color.themeRgb + ', .75)', 'rgba('+ app.color.themeRgb + ', .95)'];
            chartData = stockInAmount;
            chartStroke = {
                show: false,
                curve: 'smooth',
                lineCap: 'butt',
                colors: 'rgba(' + app.color.blackRgb + ', .25)',
                width: 2,
                dashArray: 0,
            };
            chartPlotOptions = {
                pie: {
                    donut: {
                        background: 'transparent',
                    }
                }
            };

        } else if (chartType === 'line') {
            chartColors = [app.color.theme];

            chartData = [{
                name: chartTitle,
                data: orderData
            }];
            chartStroke = {
                curve: 'straight',
                width: 2
            };
        }

        var chartOptions = {
            chart: {
                height: chartHeight,
                type: chartType,
                toolbar: {
                    show: false
                },
                sparkline: {
                    enabled: true
                },
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            colors: chartColors,
            stroke: chartStroke,
            plotOptions: chartPlotOptions,
            series: chartData,
            grid: {
                show: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                theme: 'dark',
                x: {
                    show: false
                },
                y: {
                    title: {
                        formatter: function (seriesName) {
                            return ''
                        }
                    },
                    formatter: (value) => { return ''+ value },
                }
            },
            xaxis: {
                labels: {
                    show: true
                }
            },
            yaxis: {
                labels: {
                    show: true
                }
            }
        };
        chart[x] = new ApexCharts(elm, chartOptions);
        chart[x].render();
        x++;
    });



  var serverChartOptions = {
    chart: {
      height: '100%',
      type: 'bar',
      toolbar: {
        show: false
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: false,
        columnWidth: '55%',
        endingShape: 'rounded'
      },
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    grid: {
        show: true,
        borderColor: false,
    },
    stroke: {
      show: false
    },
    colors: ['rgba('+ app.color.whiteRgb + ', .25)', app.color.theme],
      series: [
          {
          name: 'DEBIT',
          data:  debitData
      },
          {
              name: 'CREDIT',
              data: creditData
          }],


    xaxis: {
      // categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', 30],
      labels: {
                show: true
            }
    },
    fill: {
      opacity: .65
    },
    tooltip: {
      y: {
        formatter: function (val) {
          return "BDT " + val
        }
      }
    }
  };


  var apexServerChart = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector('#chart-server'),
    serverChartOptions
  );
  apexServerChart.render();
};

fetchEarningData()
fetchMemberData()
fetchCreditData()
fetchDebitData()
fetchOrderData()

/* Controller
------------------------------------------------ */

$(document).ready(function() {
    // window.location = window.location.href;
    // setInterval(function(){
    //     window.location.reload();
    //
    // }, 3000);
    // setInterval(10000);
    // handleRenderChart()
    document.addEventListener('theme-reload',  function() {
        $('[data-render="apexchart"], #chart-server').empty();
        handleRenderChart()
    });
    let serial = 1;
    fetch(`dashboard/top-products`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            // console.log(res)
            $('#topProducts').html(res.map((topProducts) => ` <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="d-flex">
                                            <div class="position-relative mb-2">
                                                <div class="position-absolute top-0 start-0">
                                                    <span class="badge bg-theme text-theme-900 rounded-0 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center w-20px h-20px">${serial++}</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="flex-1 ps-3">
                                                <div class="mb-1"><small class="fs-9px fw-500 lh-1 d-inline-block rounded-0 badge bg-white bg-opacity-25 text-white text-opacity-75 pt-5px">${topProducts.barcode_number}</small></div>
                                                <div class="fw-500 text-white">${topProducts.title}</div>
                                                BDT ${topProducts.price}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <table class="mb-2 mt-2">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pe-3">TOTAL SOLD:</td>
                                                <td class="text-white text-opacity-75 fw-500">${topProducts.total}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="pe-3">REVENUE:</td>
                                                <td class="text-white text-opacity-75 fw-500">${topProducts.total * topProducts.price} BDT</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <a href="product/${topProducts.uuid}" class="text-decoration-none text-white"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>` ))

        })

});
```

Comment: is your sdk loading properly ?

Comment: pardon, I don't understand, are you asking about my IDE?

Answer (score 0):

it seems worked for me. ie; dynamically generate the chart div on on each function call to draw chart data

```
<div class="card" style="padding:0" id="charts">                   
    <div class="card-body" style="padding:0" id="tagchart"> 
       <div id="chart"></div>                
   </div>
```

```
var c = document.getElementById("tagchart");
var d = document.getElementById("chart");
c.removeChild(d);

var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
newdiv.setAttribute("id", "chart");
c.appendChild(newdiv);
```